# ¿Por que no funcionan mis restricciones de claves foraneas?

Tags: base-de-datos, uml, relaciones, modelorelacional

Tengo mi base de datos  `usuarios_mensaje` y lo que pasa es que mis             **restricciones de clave foranea** no funcionan, pongo el ejemplo que he hecho:

**He intentado insertar un mensaje a un usuario que no existe y me ha dejado** Segun tengo la BD no deberia, y no se realmente porque no hace efecto **las restricciones** que he puesto.

A continuacion dejo mi **BD** :

```
CREATE DATABASE usuarios_mensaje;
USE usuarios_mensaje;


CREATE TABLE usuarios(

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(50),
    usuario VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)

);


CREATE TABLE mensajes(

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    titulo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    contenido VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    createAt TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    creador VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    url_img VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (creador) REFERENCES usuarios(id)

);


CREATE TABLE etiquetas(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE etiquetas_en_mensajes(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id_mensaje INT (50) NOT NULL,
    id_etiqueta INT (50) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_mensaje) REFERENCES mensajes(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_etiqueta) REFERENCES etiquetas(id),

);
```

Comment: ¿Qué base de datos (nombre, versión, etc.) usas?

Comment: Ya lo acabo de solucionar: he puesto al final de las tablas el `ENGINE=InnoDB` y con eso me ha detectado las foraneas, no se porque por defecto no las coge. Tu pregunta me dio la pista. Gracias.

Comment: Se que ya resolviste tu problema, pero Me parece raro que tu clave foránea sea de tipo varchar y referencia una clave de tipo int, no deberían ser del mismo tipo?